# Get raw body with Retrofit in Android

Tags: android, api, http

Ok. May be the question was asked many times, but I can't find right solution.
I need to receive raw http response (it contains image bytes). But Retrofit can't parse it and throws

```
com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $
```

Retrofit interface ::

```
@GET("profile/{profileId}/avatar")
    fun getAvatar(
        @Path("profileId") profileId: String,
    ): Call<ResponseBody>
```

On this step (execute method) retrofit throws the exception

```
val call = profileApi.getAvatar1(userId).execute()
```

This is api response. And it's successful.

```
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: <-- 200 https://{bigpath}}/avatar (404ms)
{ BLA-BLA }
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: <-- END HTTP (binary 447413-byte body omitted)
```

So server sends correct response with raw image data. But retrofit tries parse it as JSON. If I set retrofit-api-method return type as `Call<ResponseBody>` or `Call<String>` it still throws same exception.

So, the question is::
How to get raw body from retrofit response ???

P.S. There're no opportunity to load image using Glide or Picasso.

P.S.S. I met same problem (`at line 1 column 1 path $`) when I tried parse empty body.

Comment: have you tried `Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON`

Comment: I tried. Than not helps.